# Check Javascript Condition Every Frame

Tags: javascript

Pretty much, my question is simple, and I did search for a similar question before posting this. I would like to know how to make Javascript code repeatedly execute while the page is open, rather than the code running once and being done or only responding to event handlers. I pretty much want the Javascript equivilant of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

But I do not want to use Jquery because it is less efficient. I want to check an === condition every single frame.

Comment: look up setInterval()

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a quick code example of how to actually incorporate it to my desired results?

Comment: *rather than the code running once and being done or only responding to event handlers* This is what you should (must) do. If your code is running non-stop, then the page would freeze. If you use a `setInterval` loop, then it is not even an efficient approach to any problem. I don't know what you are doing here, but every time you try to execute the same code repeatedly, it will not be efficient (that says jQuery is often more efficient then the code you write.)

Comment: Can you run the === on frame load or a few ms after load using setTimeout(function(){}, 20);? Is there a frame load hook?

Answer (score 3):

Use SetInterval .. inside a window.onload function

```
window.onload = function() {            
     function test() {
         alert("test");
     }
     setInterval(test, time_miliseconds);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
     var blah = whatever;
     if (done){
         clearInterval();
     }
},time_in_milliseconds);
```

loop keeps looping per your milliseconds argument.  If you want a loop thinner than a millisecond or as hard as the computer can do it then just a regular while(true){} will suffice.

Comment: Cool! I am going to be using this to check onClick handlers for many elements in a loop. One last question: What would be the best bet for making it run, assuming the frame rate is 60 per second, at exactly 60 frames per second? I am guessing about 16.6 milliseconds I set it to? But I want the condition to be checked every frame, so would 10 milliseconds suffice?

Comment: time_in_milliseconds = 1000; //per second; time_in_milliseconds /= 60;

Comment: setInterval is non-blocking so like derek mentioned above this would be the way to go if you're trying to do something like a game